# How To Encapsulate I/O and Similar Promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, promise, es6-promise

There are many I/O operations--requests to other servers, database access, file access--that are or should be promises. However, for encapsulation, higher level calls that may be making server requests (e.g. to Google recaptcha or Cloudinary), database calls (e.g. PostgreSQL, Mongo, ReDis) or just reading a file.

Ideally, these would have the format:

```
functionCall()
.then(FC1)
.then(FC2)
.catch()
```

The calling parent shouldn't have to know about the internals of the call or is subsquent then or catch clauses. They should be, as I understand it, similar to:

```
highLevelFuncionCall()
.then(()=>{
   functionCall() //and all its then/catch clauses
}
.then(HLFC1)
.then(HLFC2)
.catch()
```

However, it doesn't seem to work that way. Processing proceeds to HLFC1 without waiting for FC1 and FC2, even though their processing is required first.

How can it be structured so the dependent promises are invisible to the higher level caller?

Thanks,

David

Comment: `then(resolve, reject)` where resolve/reject is a function that returns Promise. But `() =>´{ functionCall() }` returns undefined and resolves immediately. Try to remove curly.

Comment: About scopes: there is no requirement to resolve/reject internals to next function. `functionCall` can look like `function functionCall() { return asyncCall().then(()=>Promise.resolve()) }`. It will dump any data, resolve undefined (as a Promise) and keep chaining.

Comment: The trouble is I need a way for functionCall and its then clause FC1 and FC2 or it catch error handler to be called before it returns to the highLevelFunctionCall chain. 

How can a promise and its then clauses be kept as an atomic operation? For example, if functionCall reads a database, parses the response while highLevelFunctionCall is processing the data, for example, verifying a login.

In the Angular client we have ended up emitting messages when the then clauses complete. I never liked that, and haven't seen it used in Nodejs on the server.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand properly (based on comments), this should simulate described scenarios:

```js
function getResolved() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => window.setTimeout(resolve, 500, 'ok'));
}

function getRejected() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => window.setTimeout(reject, 500, 'error!'));
}

function progressChain(functionCall) {
  return getResolved() // HLF1
  .then(() => {
    return functionCall() // functionCall with then/catch
    .then(getResolved)
    .then(() => console.log('functionCall resolved'))
    .catch((err) => { // FCC
      console.log('Argh!! functionCall failed!');
      throw err; // rethrow err to chain
    });
  })
  .then(getResolved) // HLF2
  .then((res) => console.log(res)) // HLF3
  .catch((err) => console.log(err)); // HLC
}

// both resolved and rejected scenario (synced)
progressChain(getResolved)
.then(() => progressChain(getRejected))
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused. `getResolved` returns a promise and is used everywhere in the example. It seems that it needs a dummy Promise at the start of each then chain and returns the promise and the resolve then chain to the caller. 

function encap (){
    return new Promise((resolve)=>resolve("encap start"))
    .then((x) => {console.log('encap resolved 1 ' + x); return "encap1"})
    .then((x) => {console.log('encap resolved 2 '+ x); return "encap2"})
    .catch((err) => { // FCC
        console.log('Argh!! functionCall failed!');
        throw err; // rethrow err to chain
    });
}

Comment: @DavidNJ This is only example. getResolved and getRejected are dummy Promises that behaves like async call somewhere that either successes or fails. It can start with just only one and then resolve only values ofc. The point is that you should probably rethrow error from inner catch..

Comment: Another thing is missing return value from resolve function. I can't direct you to concrete one article, but there are tons of articles about Promises. Just google it..

Comment: I think I've read just about everything printed on promises. Tried multiple libraries. The expectation is that returning a promise chain should execute the chain before returning. It returns on the first promise and treats the encapsulated promise chain and the encapsulating chain independently.

The desired behavior would be as if the encapsulated chain was inserted into the the encapsulating chain.

Comment: @DavidNJ can you add real code into your question? I'm really curious how it could happen because behaviour of Promise chains is strictly given

Comment: Code added. It is in a NodeJS environment and the default Stackoverflow code display (the current one) wouldn't work.

Comment: @DavidNJ You are passing promise value to then which is evaluated immediately. Then works with function type args, first for resolving and optional second for rejecting. Try 
.then(() => T1("fred")).then(() => T1("whatever")) instead